# Discord bot is not joining voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
from discord.utils import get
from discord import Game

client = Bot(command_prefix = BOT_PREFIX)

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    await ctx.send('Joined {}'.format(channel))
```

I just wanted to make a simple method that allows my discord bot to join a channel. I have looked at multiple threads and some of them are outdated because they were before discord.py migrated to v1.0. I have used type() and dir() to check what type the channel is and also see what methods it has. I compared it to the API from discord.py and a problem I found was that the dir() made a field called `connect` but the API shows that the `channel` object has a method called `connect()`. I am stuck at the moment trying to figure out how to make the discord bot join as it seems the `connect()` method does not allow me to connect as it does not allow me to continue with the method after I try using that `connect()` method. All help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the message from `channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel`.
Test this :)

```
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
voice = await channel.connect()
await ctx.send('Joined {}'.format(channel))
```